# How does the html and css effect achieve like the google search example?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to use browser debug model to catch the style css and js, but I still confuse about the truth how to achive the effec, like the picture screeshots.
Core effect is : **click the words and then extends the content!**.Can I do this just via css, as less as js ? Beacause I want to embed the effect into **sciter** , a framwork which can't support js!
[image: css click efffect like google]

Comment: effect is called an *"accordion"*. Lots of scripts around on the web for those

Comment: it can be done with a hidden radio input and css animation or transition, but it's not ideal... see for instance https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/height-issue-with-pure-css-accordion-faq/